# "Input string was not in a correct format." when trying to add new record to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm new into c# programming and I'm trying for a while to debug this but so far I found no answer that could help me.
I'm trying to add a new record into a MSSQL database and I get the following error each time:

> {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

My code is below:

```
        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=CODRINMA\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=TrafficManager;Integrated Security=True";
        string insert = "INSERT INTO Companii (IDCompanie, Denumire, Adresa, Oras, CUI) VALUES (@IDCompanie, @Denumire, @Adresa, @Oras, @CUI)";
      try
        {

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDCompanie", txtID.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Denumire", txtDenumire.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adresa", txtAdresa.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Oras", int.Parse(cmbOrase2.SelectedValue.ToString()));
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUI", txtCUI.Text);
               int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               MessageBox.Show(val + "Compania a fost adaugata cu succes!");
               con.Close();
               this.Dispose();

            }
        }
     catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
    }
```

The combobox Orase2 is binded with some values from a MSSQL database. Please, need some help! Thanks.

Comment: `The combobox Orase2 is binded with some values from a MSSQL database` - then why do you cast it to string and then parse back to `int` (and fail in the process)?

Comment: @GSerg - thought I have to parse the selected value into string because those values are FK to another table called `Orase`. What do I have to do?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - it may be, but I've used `con.Close();` to some other forms and worked smoothly, no errors caused. But I'll try.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have changed the combobox.ValueMember and it worked.

Comment: @cdrrr Hi, since you answered your question alone, please post it as an answer, in order for others that may have the same problem, to have a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `combobox.ValueMember` and it worked. I was converting to string when in fact I already had the int value.